# Responsive Mobile Menu - Jquery Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a responsive jquery mobile menu. The problem that I am having is the jquery coding by default hides the menu and only when the image is clicked the navigation expands. This functionality is fine except when being viewed on a desktop. Because it is set up by default to not appear it is not shown.

I was hoping someone could help me to show the navigation on the desktop version and when a width threshold is crossed by default the navigation doesn't appear until it is clicked. This is so when someone visits the website on a mobile device the screen isn't covered with the menu. I was also having problems retracting the menu when the image is pressed again.

I have have uploaded my projected onto jsfiddle. `link` http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved reasonable quickly and easily using Bootstrap.

### Example

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

### Documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

### Code Example (from above link)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

### JSFiddle (above example)

http://jsfiddle.net/rlgod/7d1szLkh/